# HTML table with ueven cells elements in even rows ( colspan )

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to built a very simple diagram or flow chart representation of buildings .

```
$floors = array(     array( 'app_1','app_2','app_2_A' ),
                            array( 'app_3','app_4','app_5'),
                            array( 'app_6','app_7', 'app_8','app_9') ,
                            array( 'app_10','app_11', 'app_12','app_13') ,
                            array( 'app_14','app_15', 'app_16') ,
                ); 

echo "<table border='2'>";

foreach ($floors as $floor ) {

    $total_app = count( $floor);

    echo "<tr>";

     for($i = 0;$i < $total_app; $i++){
      echo "<td colspan=" .$total_app.  ">";
          echo $floor[$i] . ' ( ' . $total_app . ' ) '; //brackets only for debug
           echo "</td>";
     }

    echo  "</tr>";

}   


echo "</table>";
```

The result is :

[image: Resultingtable]

Problem is : The client wants all the rows to be of equal width , and not all the floors has the same number of apartments.

So I thought I will use 'colspan'. ( in code `echo "<td colspan=" .$total_app.  ">";` )

Problem (2) : The script needs to work on 100´s of different buildings, so anything less than a full dynamic calculation for the 'colspan' will not work.

`Colspan` , as I understand it , is actually relative to the max number of cells i have ( the row with largest number of elements ).

If that is true , then I need to know which array element ( floor ) has the highest count ( apartments ) - and then set this as the header - but I am not sure how to do it.

so

1. how can I count the elements inside the nested array and compare them to see the "most populated floor"
2. having done that - how can I calculate the `colspan` for each floor´s row of apartments in relation to that max. ( `colspan` can have only int() and not fractions or percentage )
3. A building is thought of as going from bottom to top, where as a table from top to bottom, so I need to flip the array , but keep the calculations of 'colspan'
4. last but not least - I might be looking  at this all wrong and there might be an easier way to achieve the wanted result ( maybe divs? ) - but I can not see one now - so if one exist - please do 'slap' me and show me the way ..

**EDIT I**

Like Said before : the solution must be flexible for all configurations :
Example :

```
$floors = array(     array( 'app_1','app_2','app_2_A','app_2_B','app_2_C', 'app_2_D'),
                                array( 'app_3','app_4','app_5'),
                                array( 'app_6','app_7') ,
                                array( 'app_10','app_11', 'app_12','app_13') ,
                                array( 'app_14') ,
                    );
```

So any attempt to "hardcode" calculations of colspan will fail..
I need the Rows (floors) to be equal in width, and for the cells ( apartments ) to fill each row to full in such a way that if for example I have 2 apartments ,each will be 50% in width, if I have 4 apartments ,each will be 25% , 3 apartments - 33% and so on .

The question is how to achieve that with `colspan` if possible, or with any other method ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly colspan is stand of the row has 3 column, but I want the row **combine** all column in single cell, you could use colspan.

```
<?
$max_app = 0;
foreach( $floors as $floor ){
    $max_app = max(count($floor), $max_app);
}

echo "<table border='2'>";
foreach( $floors as $floor ){
    echo "<tr>";
    for( $a=0;$a<count($floor);$a++ ){
        if( $a+1 == count($floor) && $a+1 < $max_app ){
            //last cell, total number of cell in floor does not equals to $max_app
            echo "<td colspan='" . ($max_app - $a) . "'>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>";
        }
        echo $floor[$a];
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The alternative solution is using DIV with float: left; but the width of the DIV needed to know. Cause your requirement: all cell need using same width.

**EDIT 1**

Are you want a solution that ALL row is same width, and all cell width is same in each row???

[image: share width in row, but all row is same width]

```
<?
echo "<table border='0'>";
foreach( $floors as $floor ){
    echo "<tr><td><table border='1' width='100%'><tr>";
    $percent = ceil( 100 / count($floor) );
    foreach($floor as $app){
        print("<td width='{$percent}%'>{$app}</td>");
    }
    echo "</tr></table></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: 1 - not all cells need to have the same width - but all `rows` need . ( floors) . 2 - your solutions gives and undefined index error , which i can fix, but also - it will not work for all configurations - see my edit I

Comment: thx, and also modified the code, check it out of the screen shot: http://imgur.com/M4vvWZv

Comment: This is much better .. but what I aim for is for the cells to FILL the row ,. so if have only 2 cells , each will be half of the total ..

Comment: Check it out my **EDIT 1** section, but the layout not equals to your copy.

Comment: YES !! this is what I need . And it works great ! what I was missing was this : ` $percent = ceil( 100 / count($floor) );` .. perfect ! thanks !

Comment: BTW - is it possible, for sake of correct markup to do that with `colspan` ??

Comment: Why tables at all... this isn't the early 2000's... :(

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, why nest table? >> Because you need a fixed outer (Per row, per floor), and every cells in row are shared row width. Making option: (A) using outer table (same as my version), (B) using fixed width of DIV instead of outer table

Comment: You should either use floated divs with % width, or you should use one separate table per row. This way you don't have to deal with colspan at all.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: DIV

```
<style>
    .floor{ width: 800px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; margin: 6px 0px; }
    .app{ width: 110px; float: left; padding: 2px; margin: 0px 4px; border: 1px solid blue; }
    .spacer{clear: both; }
</style>

<?
foreach( $floors as $floor ){
    echo "<div class='floor'>";
    for( $a=0;$a<count($floor);$a++ )
        echo "<div class='app'>{$floor[$a]}</div>";
    echo "<div class='spacer'></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

[image: Table vs div]

**EDIT 1:**

[image]

Limitation & remark:

1. you need provide the outer div(.floor) width to calculation
2. in coding, 14 means left & right x (app.border: 1 + app.padding: 2 + app.margin: 4)
3. in coding, 800 means floor.width - ( left & right x (floor.border: 1 + floor.padding: 4) )

Coding:

```
<style>
    .floor{ width: 810px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; margin: 6px 0px; }
    .app{ float: left; padding: 2px; margin: 0px 4px; border: 1px solid blue; }
    .spacer{clear: both; }
</style>

<?
foreach( $floors as $floor ){
    echo "<div class='floor'>";
    // 14px = 2 x (app.border: 1 + app.padding: 2 + app.margin: 4)
    // 800px = floor.width - ( 2 x (floor.border: 1 + floor.padding: 4) )
    $percent = floor( 1 / count($floor) * 800) - 14;
    for( $a=0;$a<count($floor);$a++ )
        echo "<div class='app' style='width: {$percent}px'>{$floor[$a]}</div>";
    echo "<div class='spacer'></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Again, The original problem is that I need the rows ( floors ) to be equal in width, and the cells to FILL them to full. so if I have 3 cells ( appartments ) each will be 33% , and if I have two , each will be 50% and if I have 4 , each will be 25% and so on... and I want to know how to calculate the `colspan` for that ..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen , please take a look at this section, using DIV only. PS, there are very minor bug, a ***one*** pixel will be missing for it can't really divide by column, such as 3, 7, 9, etc

Answer (score 1):

As you have got the right answer above, but still here is one too.

```
$floors = array(     array( 'app_1','app_2','app_2_A' ),
                            array( 'app_3','app_4','app_5'),
                            array( 'app_6','app_7', 'app_8','app_9','app_90') ,
                            array( 'app_10','app_11', 'app_12','app_13') ,
                            array( 'app_14','app_15', 'app_16') ,
                ); 
$maxCol = 0;
foreach($floors as $f){
  $curCnt = count($f);

  if($maxCol < $curCnt) $maxCol = $curCnt;
}

echo "<table border='2'>";

foreach ($floors as $floor ) {

    $total_app = count( $floor);
    $colSpan = $maxCol%$total_app;

    echo "<tr>";

     for($i = 0;$i < $total_app; $i++){
      echo "<td colspan=" .(($i==($total_app-1))?$colSpan+1:1).  ">";
          echo $floor[$i] . ' ( ' . $total_app . ' ) '; //brackets only for debug
           echo "</td>";
     }

    echo  "</tr>";

}   


echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this ??? try this

```
$floors = array(     array( 'app_1','app_2','app_2_A' ),
                            array( 'app_3','app_4','app_5'),
                            array( 'app_6','app_7', 'app_8','app_9') ,
                            array( 'app_10','app_11', 'app_12','app_13') ,
                            array( 'app_14','app_15', 'app_16') ,
                ); 

echo '<div style="border:#000000 solid 2px; padding:2px;width:100%;" >';

foreach ($floors as $floor ) {

    $total_app = count( $floor);

    echo '<div style=" padding:2px;" > ';

     for($i = 0;$i < $total_app; $i++){
      echo '<div style="border:#0000cc solid 1px; float:left; padding:2px;width:100px;" >';
          echo $floor[$i] . ' ( ' . $total_app . ' ) '; //brackets only for debug
           echo '</div> ';
     }

    echo  '</div> <br> <br> ';

}   


echo '</div>';
```

Comment: No, what you did there is only changing the table to divs , the result is the same .. What I need is for the cells to FILL 100% of the row , no matter how many are there ..

Comment: yes, look at @Allen Chak Edit in his answer, second example .. The question was how to achieve that with `colspan`